# Weak convergence of multivariate stochastic processes

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

in textbooks I find only results about the weak convergence of univariate stochastic processes. I am looking for a reference text which treats also the convergence of multivariate (vector) stochastic processes.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Ciao

Karl

Comment: When we say weak convergence of stochastic objects, indeed we are talking about the convergence of associated measures, so to me it makes no difference whether the stochastic process takes value in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ as long as $d$ being finite. Nevertheless, if you find it important to your research, you can check *Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes* by Jacod and Shiryaev, e.g. page 348, section 3b, they consider the weak convergence of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$-valued càdlàg processes.